# setting value of textbox from button onclick using inline javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox and some buttons with an integer defined in `value` and `data-for-count` attributes.
I know how to add the count value using jQuery in an external .js file, but is it possible to do this without calling a function?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="thediv">
        <input type="number" class="count" value="10" min="10" max="100" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="quick" value="10" data-for-count="10" />
        <input type="button" class="quick" value="20" data-for-count="20" />
        <input type="button" class="quick" value="30" data-for-count="30" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<input type="button" class="quick" value="77" data-for-count="77" onclick="$(this).closest('.wrap').find('input.count').val($(this).data('for-count'))" />
```

It fails since it's jQuery and not pure javascript, but it displays what I want to do.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="thediv">
    <input type="number" class="count" value="10" min="10" max="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="10" data-for-count="10" />
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="20" data-for-count="20" />
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="30" data-for-count="30" />
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="quick" value="77" data-for-count="77" onclick="$(this).closest('.wrap').find('input.count').val($(this).data('for-count'))" />
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be external, drop a `<script>` tag on that page instead.

Comment: yeah thats true. didnt think of that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" class="quick" value="10" data-for-count="10" onclick="document.querySelector('.count').value = this.dataset['forCount'];" />
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="thediv">
    <input type="number" class="count" value="10" min="10" max="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="10" data-for-count="10" />
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="20" data-for-count="20" />
    <input type="button" class="quick" value="30" data-for-count="30" />
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="quick" value="10" data-for-count="10" onclick="document.querySelector('.count').value = this.dataset['forCount'];" />
```

Comment: I would recommend adding an explanation along with this answer.